# srun not found Snakemake on SLURM

Tags: slurm, snakemake

I am having trouble getting my workflow to run on a new SLURM cluster. I'm not super familiar with slurm so I am a bit stumped with this.

I am executing a workflow like so on the head node:
`snakemake -d .test/ --use-conda -j1 --slurm`

Snakemake successfully schedules the job via slurm, but it instantly fails:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Your conda installation is not configured to use strict channel priorities. This is however crucial for having robust and correct environments (for details, see https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html). Please consider to configure strict priorities by executing 'conda config --set channel_priority strict'.
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 2
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Provided resources: mem_mb=4000, mem_mib=3815, disk_mb=1000, disk_mib=954
Select jobs to execute...
/bin/sh: 1: srun: not found
[Wed Jul 12 16:06:24 2023]
Error in rule fastp:
  [...]  
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

So the problem seems to be that snakemake is using `/bin/sh` to execute the `srun` command, and the command doesn't exist.

I tried using a jobscript like so:
`snakemake -d .test/ --use-conda -j1 --slurm --jobscript test-jobscript.sh`

`test-jobscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# properties = {properties}
{exec_job}
```

I've also tried submitting the snakemake command via `sbatch` in a shell script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH -p main # partition (queue)
#SBATCH -c 2 # number of cores
#SBATCH --mem 10000 # memory pool for all cores
#SBATCH -t 0-2:00 # time (D-HH:MM)
#SBATCH -o slurm.%N.%j.out # STDOUT
#SBATCH -e slurm.%N.%j.err # STDERR
mamba activate snakemake
snakemake -d .test/ --use-conda -j1 --slurm
```

None of these have worked unfortunately, and I'm out of ideas, so I would appreciate any advice!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was not related to Snakemake, it was due to the fact that the compute nodes in the SLURM cluster did not have `slurm-client` installed. This meant that the compute nodes did not have `srun` available and thus the failure in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I'll interpret and answer your question as: "How can I get `snakemake` to run on a SLURM-based cluster".

You can use the [`--profile` feature](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles) to handle the job configuration and submission. A very good repository with various profiles and options to choose from is [`smk-simple-slurm` on GitHub](https://github.com/jdblischak/smk-simple-slurm).

A semi-adapted version of the [`simple` submission profile](https://github.com/jdblischak/smk-simple-slurm/blob/main/simple/config.yaml) for you as an example:

```
cluster:
  mkdir -p logs/{rule} &&
  sbatch
    --partition={resources.partition}
    --cpus-per-task={threads}
    --mem={resources.mem_mb}
    --job-name=smk-{rule}-{wildcards}
    --output=logs/{rule}/{rule}-{wildcards}-%j.out
default-resources:
  - partition=main
  - mem_mb=10000
  - time="00:02:00"
restart-times: 3
max-jobs-per-second: 10
max-status-checks-per-second: 1
local-cores: 1
latency-wait: 60
jobs: 500
keep-going: True
rerun-incomplete: True
printshellcmds: True
scheduler: greedy
use-conda: True
```

- Place it e.g. in your workflow directory as `slurm_profile/config.yaml`
- Call `snakemake` like you would do for a local execution and point it towards that folder:

```py
snakemake -d .test/ --profile slurm_profile/
```

`--use-conda` and the other options can then be handled from within the `--profile`